# Branch / merge management in Subversion 1.5

Tags: svn, version-control

I've used subversion for a  while, and used the svnmerge.py script for a while in my old job to manage merges between branches. I believe Subversion 1.5 is now out, and was supposed to have some branch / merge management system integrated with it.

So, can someone give me a quick overview of how to track merges in a branch with Subversion 1.5? Are there any pitfalls with using this support? Do I need to ensure all the team upgrades to 1.5 before using this support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Usage

Merge tracking is managed by the client and stored in a property ([svn:mergeinfo](http://subversion.tigris.org/merge-tracking/design.html)).

To use merge tracking you just merge as usual but without the revision range:

```
svn merge trunkURL
```

The client will take care of reading the properties to see what revision(s) need to be merged in and then update the properties with the newly-merged revision(s).

[Here](http://blog.red-bean.com/sussman/?p=92) is a pretty basic overview of the process.

#### Pitfalls, etc.

I personally haven't run into any problems with merge tracking, but my usage of the feature has been pretty light.

#### Upgrading

There are two upgrades you'll need to do to get merge tracking:

1. Server: Your server **must** be running 1.5 to get merge tracking support.
2. Client: You can use a 1.x client against a 1.5 server, **but you won't get merge tracking.**

Just upgrade everyone.

Answer (score 1):

An addition to Chris's post:

You may also have to upgrade the repository itself, if you run into "Retrieval of mergeinfo unsupported" messages. The command to run on the server to do this is,

```
svnadmin upgrade REPOS_PATH
```

where REPOS_PATH is the local path to your repository of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you've built your repository with the ~ svn-merge.py command you can upgrade your repository to use svn native merge tracking with the XXX command.